# One GCE ingress on GKE is causing a different GCE ingress to serve default backend

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using external-DNS, for extra background.

I setup one service, deployment, and ingress for application "A," and it all works as expected and I can reach application A at the specified URL. Then I setup a similar thing for application "B," and and now I *can* reach application B, but if I hit the URL specified for application A, I get the `default backend - 404` message. I haven't seen this issue before, what is the problem? Below are the service, deployment, and ingress manifests for A and for B:

A:service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-A
spec:
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    run: my-app-A
  type: NodePort
```

A:deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-A
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-app-A
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app-A
          image: this-is-my-docker-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: my-app-A-secrets
            - configMapRef:
                name: my-app-A-configmap
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

A:ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-A
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "A.myurl.com"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "A.myurl.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app-A
          servicePort: 80
  - host: "my-app-A-namespace.clusterbase.myurl.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app-A
          servicePort: 80
```

For the manifests for B, replace all instances of "A" with "B", and replace `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "A.myurl.com"` with just `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "myurl.com"`.

Comment: can you check to make sure both URLs resolve to the correct IP addresses? A.myurl.com should resolve to the IP address of Ingress my-app-A. I suspect both urls are resolving to the same IP address and so all requests are going through the same ingress.

Comment: On that above note, you can configure a single ingress resource for both [host paths](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) so that 1 ingress is serving both backends.

Comment: @PatrickW the issue is that for some reason, the ingresses both have the same loadbalancer IP... I would like to make a single ingress resource, but I am worried about how external-dns will work. i.e. I want A.myurl.com and myurl.com to resolve. I will also be added cert-manager for HTTPS once this is completed.

Comment: if you use a single Ingress, you can have both names resolve to the same IP address and the Ingress will route traffic based on the host path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the name of the namespace+ingress were too long, and the resources that get created in the background ended up with the same name, since they have a 64 character limit and the unique part was truncated. I filed a bug here that explains in it more detail.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/537

You will hit this issue if the first 64 characters of `<namespace>-<ingress>` are not unique.